# Reference request for Chen's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I would like to mention about Chen's Theorem, which states that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is has at most two prime factors. 
In my paper and I would like to reference his paper which he proves this, but I just don't know where I can find it. Could someone please tell me which paper this is? Thank you very much!

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying it is *not* the reference given in the relevant article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @njuffa oops. somehow i didn't see it the first time around, but now i see it. thanks!